# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'final_image' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, python-tesseract, masking

The below code is related to aadhaar masking whenever try to execute these codes I got these issues.

What's the problem?

if I change `final_image` I got other issues like local variable 'x' referenced before the assignment

```
def aadhar_mask_and_ocr(thres_image, resized_image):
    d = pytesseract.image_to_data(thres_image, output_type=pytesseract.Output.DICT)
    keys = list(d.keys())
    number_pattern = r"(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)"
    n_boxes = len(d['text'])
    c = 0
    temp = []
    UID = []
    for i in range(n_boxes):
        if int(d['conf'][i]) > 20:
            if re.match(number_pattern, d['text'][i]):
                if c<2:
                    (x, y, w, h) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])
                    final_image = cv2.rectangle(resized_image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 255), -1)
                    temp.append(d['text'][i])
                    c+=1
                elif (c>=2) and (d['text'][i] in temp):
                    (x, y, w, h) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])
                    final_image = cv2.rectangle(resized_image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 255), -1)
                elif c==2:
                    UID = temp + [ d['text'][i]]
                    c+=1
                else:
                    continue
    final_image = cv2.resize(final_image, None, fx=0.33, fy=0.33)
    return final_image, UID

# Command-line argument
# ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True,
#     help = "Path to the image to be scanned")
# args = vars(ap.parse_args())
image = cv2.imread('/content/img1.jpeg')

thres_image, resized_image = preprocessing(image)
masked_image, UID = aadhar_mask_and_ocr(thres_image, resized_image)
```

**ERROR**

````
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-231e4bfbf02b> in <module>
      7 
      8 thres_image, resized_image = preprocessing(image)
----> 9 masked_image, UID = aadhar_mask_and_ocr(thres_image, resized_image)
     10 
     11 print('Masked digits in given image. Displaying...')

<ipython-input-43-131f3ed0ec89> in aadhar_mask_and_ocr(thres_image, resized_image)
     23                 else:
     24                     continue
---> 25     final_image = cv2.resize(final_image, None, fx=0.33, fy=0.33)
     26     return final_image, UID

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'final_image' referenced before assignment ```
````

Comment: final_image only exists under certain conditions - i.e., *c<2* or *(c>=2) and (d['text'][i] in temp)* and even then only if re.match does not return None

Comment: Exactly, and the same applies to x, y, w, h.